# Scala: Reading data from scylla throws exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, scylla

I am new to scala and to run a simple query to retrieve some data from scylla. Here is my code:

```
val my_name = "test"
val cluster = ScyllaConnector.getCluster(clusterIpString, scyllaPreferredDc, scyllaUsername, scyllaPassword)
val session = cluster.connect(keySpace)
val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = session.prepare(GOID_QUERY)
val nameResults = session.execute(preparedStatement.bind(my_name))
val nameResult = nameResults.one()
if(nameResult != null){
  println("Here")
  val id_recent = nameResult.getSet("id_recent",  classOf[String])
  println(id_recent)
}
session.close()
cluster.close()
```

Throws:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not
> found for requested operation: [varchar <->
> java.util.Set<java.lang.String>]  at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:526)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:506)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$200(CodecRegistry.java:140)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:211)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:208)
> at
> shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
> at
> shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
> at
> shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
> at shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
> at shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)    at
> shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)   at
> shadeio.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.lookupCodec(CodecRegistry.java:480)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:448)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.codecFor(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:73)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getSet(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:318)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getSet(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getSet(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:307)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getSet(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
> at
> com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getSet(AbstractGettableData.java:215)
> at
> class.path$.main(CodeName.scala:184)
> at
> class.path.main(CodeName.scala)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I am sure the problem rises in the `getSet` line where it's asking for `classOf[String]` but I'm not sure what to replace it with.

Here is my table definition:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table name_table
(
    name       text,
    id_recent  text,
    primary key (name)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incompatible types - you have `text` type in the database, but you're trying to retrieve it as a set of strings (`[varchar <-> java.util.Set<java.lang.String>]` message directly says about that).

Replace `getSet` with `getString`, and if you need a set, then you need to construct it yourself from retrieved string